# zsh - how to go back to previous directory?

Tags: shell, zsh

i just bought a new mac book. in my prevous mac with zsh i was able to do the following command to go back to the previous directory:

zsh:     `-`

in bash this would be : `cd -`

but now in zsh although autoCD features work this particular one seems broken. when i type hypen in the terminal it shows two dashes here is a photo of the shell after i type in a single dash: [image]

After i hit enter it does not give an error. it simply does nothing. if i swtich to bash and do `cd -`  - it works fine.

my current version:
[image]

note: if i do `cd -` in zsh it works. but i wanted to not have to type `cd` as usual.

finally here is a sreenshot of the issue showing what works and what doesn't using zsh: [image]

update if i try to use alias i get the following error:
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

add

```
alias -- -="cd -"
```

to your `~/.zshrc` file and reload zsh and  `cd -` should work

Comment: Works. Why did you use --

Comment: If you don't use `--`, you will get an error message that `-=` is a bad option. This is because `-` normally introduces a flag. To tell `alias` not to treat `-` as the prefix to a flag but as an argument, you use `--` before `-`.
`--` tells commands that what follows should be treated as arguments, not as options.